# VB.NET - System.ArgumentException while Sorting DataGridView

Tags: sql, vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I want to sort a DataGridView by columns.

I m using SQL to fill my DataTable, to simplify lets assume that the query is :

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
FROM Table
```

After that, I initialize the DataGridView DataSource :

```
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable
```

In this case, when i click on the column head of the DataGridView, it works just fine.
But when I try to decode one filed, the exception bellow occures :

`System.ArgumentException: [DECODE(X) is not a valid string input sorting....`

The query that raises the issue :

```
SELECT DECODE(X, '0', 'No', '1', 'Yes'), Y, Z
FROM Table
```

Any Ideas Please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had just to use an Alias to rename the column.

What I did understand from this problem is that the DataTable use the name `DECODE(X)` instead of `X`.

So the query should be :

```
SELECT DECODE(X, '0', 'No', '1', 'Yes') AS X, Y, Z
FROM Table
```